# Access Names Defined Outside Module

Tags: rust

Full working example:

How do you access "Example" from inside the "tests" module?

`src/main.rs`:

```rust
struct Example {}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn example() {
        // Example is out of scope
    }
}
```

Comment: [How to Write Tests](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-01-writing-tests.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can access parent module's namespace with `super`:

```
struct Example {}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {

    use super::Example;

    #[test]
    fn example() {
        // Example is out of scope
    }
}
```